# Loading compiled javascript in nw.js crashes app on macos

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nwjs

Ive built a nw.js app. it runs fine on both win and macos. on windows ive compiled the js as per documentation using nwjc and it works fine. Since confuscating with nwjc requires doing it per OS, ive done the same with the exact same js file on macos. however, it kills the app when i start it. I am a windows user, so mac is abit unfamiliar for me. 
I have read, googled and i'm at a loss. So heres my 2 questions:

1. Is there a way i can see any crashlogs for nw.js on macos so i can further debug?
2. if im completely unable to use compiled.js, do u have any alternative suggestions on how i can inject my js without it being visible for users of the app

I am using the latest nwjs sdk build 0.29.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the nw.js build in use. I tried nightly build 30, and its now working as intended with nwjc compiled js on macos.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a hassle using windows and doing a compilation with nwjs. I would suggest if you can have a VM and install ubuntu or any linux distro. Then you can just have a build your app using nwjs-phoenix which is a little easier: https://github.com/evshiron/nwjs-builder-phoenix

Comment: Thanks for replying! I've compiled using nwbuilder on windows. it did a mac compilation aswell, but that completely failed. i will try phoenix from win and see =) But that surely wont handle nwjc binary compilation without being on a mac?

Comment: I'm using linux and I can compile win, linux and mac easily. nwjs-builder-phoenix does is to download necessary depedencies for the app to run in different OS. You can also select which Architectrure be it 32bit or 64bit

Comment: Yeah, but i am asking about confuscating the sourcecode using nwjc, not builds & archs.  http://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Protect%20JavaScript%20Source%20Code/